# Move the annotation on Google Map like Uber iOS application in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to develop an application based on Uber and Ola like concept. So for this i need to integrate the Google Map for the pick up and drop location ion iOS. So please tell me how to achieve the Moving annotation(car)animation in iOS using the Google map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**using Swift 3.1**

```swift
        var oldCoodinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CDouble((data.value(forKey: "lat") as? CLLocationCoordinate2D)), CDouble((data.value(forKey: "lng") as? CLLocationCoordinate2D)))
        var newCoodinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CDouble((data.value(forKey: "lat") as? CLLocationCoordinate2D)), CDouble((data.value(forKey: "lng") as? CLLocationCoordinate2D)))
        driverMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
        driverMarker.rotation = getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate: oldCoodinate, toCoordinate: newCoodinate)
        //found bearing value by calculation when marker add
        driverMarker.position = oldCoodinate
        //this can be old position to make car movement to new position
        driverMarker.map = mapView_
        //marker movement animation
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(Int(2.0), forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({() -> Void in
            driverMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
            driverMarker.rotation = CDouble(data.value(forKey: "bearing"))
            //New bearing value from backend after car movement is done
        })
        driverMarker.position = newCoodinate
        //this can be new position after car moved from old position to new position with animation
        driverMarker.map = mapView_
        driverMarker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.5))
        driverMarker.rotation = getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate: oldCoodinate, toCoordinate: newCoodinate)
        //found bearing value by calculation
        CATransaction.commit()
```

```swift
extension Int {
    var degreesToRadians: Double { return Double(self) * .pi / 180 }
}
extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}
```

method for get bearing value from old and new coordinates

```swift
func getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate fromLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D, toCoordinate toLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Float {

        let fLat: Float = Float((fromLoc.latitude).degreesToRadians)
        let fLng: Float = Float((fromLoc.longitude).degreesToRadians)
        let tLat: Float = Float((toLoc.latitude).degreesToRadians)
        let tLng: Float = Float((toLoc.longitude).degreesToRadians)
        let degree: Float = (atan2(sin(tLng - fLng) * cos(tLat), cos(fLat) * sin(tLat) - sin(fLat) * cos(tLat) * cos(tLng - fLng))).radiansToDegrees
        if degree >= 0 {
            return degree
        }
        else {
            return 360 + degree
        }
    }
```

for Objective C code: [Move GMSMarker on Google Map Like UBER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291262/4831524)

For github: [ARCarMovement](https://github.com/antonyraphel/ARCarMovement)

Comment: Hi Antony  Thanks for the answer . it would have been better if you have some github repository for this, both in swift and objective c

Comment: @MichelleRoot, sure I will go for it

Comment: Thanks... Lemme know once you do that.. I need it urgently ofcourse and it will be helpful for others too..

Comment: @ Antony Raphel Please tell have you done the github project... It will be helpful for me.

Comment: @MichelleRoot, check the link https://github.com/antonyraphel/ARCarMovement and you need add Google Maps SDK into this project and Google maps API key. It's all hardcoded coordinates json file. You need to change the logic as per you want. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonyRaphael thanks a lot.... Can i use this using Swift? Please include that too.. using bridge header file...

Comment: yes, you can use in Swift using bridge header. Do you need that demo app also?

Comment: @antonyraphael yes please... it would be a great help for me.. If you provide me with demo app.

Comment: @MichelleRoot Swift code demo app updated. check on https://github.com/antonyraphel/ARCarMovement.git

Comment: @AntonyRaphel In your application the coordinates have been hardcoded in the json file. But instead i am getting the location(latitude and longitude) of the driver by calling the web service each time. So how to implement this in your code?? Please clarify..

Comment: @Jessicathompson `let newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(dict!["lat"] as! Float), CLLocationDegrees(dict!["long"] as! Float))` here pass your latitude and longitude from web service and if bearing value is there, then pass that value too else just pass as value 0.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel if counter < coordinateArr.count {} so what will be the coordinateArr?? do we need this loop?? if yes, what should be there? Because currently the array contains the array from json. From web service we will be getting latitude and longitude one by one..

Comment: @Jessicathompson yes, you need to pass the json data based on how you are receiving from your web service. Like every 10 or 30 seconds that you are calling web service know, then it will work fine. Don't bother about coodinateArr.

Comment: is there any example for mkmapView Swift, Thanks

Comment: why you are using  driverMarker.rotation = getHeadingForDirection(fromCoordinate: oldCoodinate, toCoordinate: newCoodinate) twice?