# How to show an user Location on Live. like Uber IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, maps

I am new to swift and Maps. I am facing problem with displaying user live location. I have to display user location like Uber and Ola. I am getting array of coordinates from server.

This is the way i am fetching coordinates from server. I want to show moving user location. see following my code.

```
 func SetUpMapsUI()
    {
        AdminAPIManager.sharedInstance.getAdminRunningStatusFromURL(){(resignationsJson)-> Void in
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(resignationsJson)
            let status = swiftyJsonVar["status"].rawString() as! String
            print("status",status)
            let message = swiftyJsonVar["message"].rawString()

            if status.isEqual("0"){
                if (message?.isEqual("No trips done so far."))!
                {
                    self.mapViewBottomCons.constant = 0
                }else
                {
                    self.mapViewBottomCons.constant = 70
                }
                self.Bottom_view.isHidden = true
                Toast.short(message: message as! String)
                return
            }
            let busVar = swiftyJsonVar["bus_details"].rawString()!
            let jsonData = busVar.data(using: .utf8)!
            let LocationArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])  as! Array< Any>
            for data in LocationArray!
            {
                let dic = data as! NSDictionary
                guard let lat = dic.value(forKey: "latitude") as? Double else {
                    return
                }
                print("latlatlatlat",lat)
                guard let lon = dic.value(forKey: "longitude") as? Double else {
                    return
                }
                print("longitude",lon)
                self.arrayMapPath.append(NewMapPath(lat: Double(lat), lon: Double(lon)))
            }
            if self.arrayMapPath.count > 0
            {
                self.drawPathOnMap()
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do u mean by live location?

Answer (score 0):

here is library that does that functionality it is written for both swift and ObjC..
[ARCarMovement](https://github.com/antonyraphel/ARCarMovement/blob/master/ARCarMovementSwift/ARCarMovementSwift/ViewController.swift)

here is a Stackoverflow [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291262/5259363) answer